# Is it possible to load contents of a resource folder that contains swift classes in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, io

I'm would like read contents of a Group/Resource folder in Xcode that contains swift files

I need to travers a folder in my iOS project. This folder shall contain Swift classes, which I would like to dynamically load through NSClassFromString.

I have tried to add those classes to the Resource folder, unfortunately I could not load those files

Is there anyway to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Swift is a compiled language, so just having .swift files won't do anything. And you can't load additional libraries at runtime on iOS.

Comment: But you can for example dynamically load a class by its name through NSClassFromString? I need to list the files (which are classes) and instantiate them one by one.